# Kentico CMS support for native iOS & Android

Tags: android, ios, mobile, kentico

We are planning to use the existing Kentico CMS environment for development of native mobile apps for iOS & Android.

Does Kentico CMS support native mobile apps development? Does it have any supported SDKs in-place?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to option Roman mentioned above, you can also take a look at https://kenticocloud.com and see if out brand new API-first cloud CMS would be better solution for what you need.

Giving the fact it's API-first you can use it on all kinds of platform including iOS and Android.

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Thanks.

Karol

Answer (score 0):

Kentico exposes [Rest API](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Kentico+REST+service) that you could easily consume by a native app. It provides you with a CRUD methods to literaly any object you have within your Kentico instance, so you could get data, process it and present in your app. Here you can find some more details [here](http://bitsorchestra.com/Idea/August-2015/Async-processing-in-Kentico).

Comment: Here is also link how to set up WebAPI in case REST does not fit: https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Using+ASP.NET+Web+API+with+Kentico